# Laravel 5.5 MDN Fetch API set session variable not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5

I am trying to set session variable on GET `fetch('/ajax-get-save-session')` request.

```
Route::get('/ajax-get-save-session', function() { session(['my_key', 'Saved Session']) });
```

And when I try to access the session variable `my_key` in different route.

```
Route::get('/access-session', function() { return session('my_key'); });
```

NULL value is returned.

This routes are registered on Laravel `web.php` and I'm using [MDN fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Anyone?

Comment: Are you accessing `/access-session` before `/ajax-get-save-session` ?

Comment: @linktoahref No. Its /ajax-get-save-session before /access-session

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using file as session driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally my mistake. I never thought [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is the one causing my problem. It says the description

```
By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init option must be set).
```

By doing :

```
fetch(url, { credentials : 'include' }).then(response => response.json())
```

SOLVED MY PROBLEM!

Comment: good you solved your problem your own ..... because my answer is right according to your question.. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your response. My code also works. Your code is the same with my code the only difference is that your using Session Facade and I'm using global session helper.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem. You are looking for this. Try this:-

```
Use Session; //if your are using laravel 5.2 then add in top in routes. php or laravel 5.2 > greater versions in web.php 
// now put data in session
Route::get('/ajax-get-save-session', function() {
 Session::put('my_key','Saved Session');
});
//Access the session
Route::get('/access-session', function() { echo Session::get('my_key') });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.5 as stated above my post. Have you tried your answer? It's not working on my end. Did you access '/ajax-get-save-session' route thru GET Ajax Request? And check if 'my_key' returns value in '/access-session' route?

Comment: What Laravel Version are you using?

Comment: i am using 5.2 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159360/discussion-between-john-roca-and-kunal).